VBA code to rotate a list of positions/names on two columns, one row up (top row will fall last) but not to include blank cells
VBA code that can rotate in sync up one row two columns with positions/names so that the top row will always fall down on last position. The code should ignore the blank cells and only rotate the cells with data. Selection of cells is A3-B18
Cells A3 and B3 should rotate to positions A6 and B6. Cells A4 and B4 should move up one row to A3 and B3. Cells A5 and B5 should move up to A4 and B4. Basically, even though the selection is much bigger, only the cells with data should take action and rotate.
Before rotation

After rotation

This is the code:
Range("A9:B9").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A29").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A10:B24").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("A9").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=3, Link:=1, DisplayAsIcon:=False, IconFileName:=False
Range("A29:B29").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A24").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A29:B29").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents Range("A3")


Why don't you ask yourself whether it is in your interest that somebody posts an answer for your homework. How would that help you to learn to use Excel? For your own good, I really hope that nobody answers your post. I suggest you try to solve it yourself, and post a detailed question about your code, if it doesn't do what is required.

Record Macro is a useful tool for generating VBA code when working with data on a worksheet. It's an excellent starting point for your VBA journey.

"Can you please assist me..." Sure, edit your question to show where you need assistance.

Thanks for your feedback community, I know how to use Record Macro already but that is not helping me solve my issue as I need the macro to skip blank cells. I will reformulate my question.

If you post your trial even the recorded macro, will help to reopen your question.

Have you tried the solution that @Blackcat provided? Does it work as you need it to?  If yes, consider to mark it as the correct answer. If not, respond with a comment beneath their answer, and explain what is wrong.

A little bit adapted to the specific request:
Sub roller()

lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("A3:B3").Cut Range("A" & lastrow + 1 & ":B" & lastrow + 1)
Range("A3:B3").Delete xlShiftUp


End Sub

